How to Enable the Postal Code Layer in Pelias with OpenStreetMap Data
How can I enable the "postalcode" layer in Pelias with OpenStreetMap data? Currently, I only have the "address" and "venue" layers available for the osm Data-Source.
The Problem:
The objects I get as an answer contain the postal code, but I cannot search for it.
"'postalcode' is an invalid layers parameter. Valid options: coarse,address,venue"
"properties": {
        "id": "way/313670734",
        "gid": "openstreetmap:venue:way/313670734",
        "layer": "venue",
        "source": "openstreetmap",
        "source_id": "way/313670734",
        "country_code": "DE",
        "name": "Berliner Dom",
        "street": "Am Lustgarten",
        "postalcode": "10178",
        "accuracy": "point",
        "country": "Germany",
        "country_gid": "whosonfirst:country:85633111",
        ...
}

What I have done so far (in a Kubernetes cluster):

Set up Elasticsearch.
Executed the Pelias schema and the Pelias OpenStreetMap importer (with osm and wof data).
Started the Pelias API.

Do I have to start other importers or integrate other pelias services to be able to search for postal codes with the autocomplete interface?
My goal would be for this request to work:
http://your.pelias.api/v1/autocomplete?text=10178&layers=postalcode
This is my pelias.json config for the importers:
"imports": {
        "adminLookup": {
          "enabled": true,
          "usePostalCities": true
        },
        "openstreetmap": {
          "download": [{
            "sourceURL": "https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany-latest.osm.pbf"
          }],
          "datapath": "/tmp/pelias/openstreetmap",
          "leveldbpath": "/tmp",
          "import": [{
            "filename": "germany-latest.osm.pbf"
          }]
        },
        "whosonfirst": {
          "datapath": "/tmp/pelias/whosonfirst",
          "importPostalcodes": true,
          "countryCode": "DE"
        }
      }
    }

